# How to add Leverage browser caching to firebase.json

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-hosting, vs-web-site-project

I'm using Firebase on Google Cloud Platform for the first time and I've uploaded my static website but now I'd like to add:

```
"headers": [ {
    "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
    "headers" : [ {
      "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value" : "*"
  } ]
  }, {
    "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
    "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Cache-Control",
    "value" : "max-age=7200"
    } ]
  }, {
    // Sets the cache header for 404 pages to cache for 5 minutes
    "source" : "404.html",
    "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Cache-Control",
    "value" : "max-age=300"
    } ]
  } ]
```

to enable Leverage browser caching, but I do not understand how to add these lines of code to the firebase.json file?
The firebase init command creates a firebase.json settings file in the root of your project's directory, but how can I change it after I've created the site?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the caching settings on your web site, change the relevant `Change-Control` header in your `firebase.json` and then rerun `firebase deploy`. This will deploy the latest `firebase.json` with your new settings, and ensure that all HTML/CSS/JS/etc files are up to date too.

If you lost your `firebase.json`, a simple default could look something like this from the [Firebase Hosting reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config):

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "app",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank,
the point is that I don't have the firebase.json file on my computer, it's created and it is in the firebase directory.
how can I change it?

Comment: if I create a new file called firebase.json in my (public) directory and once inserted what I need I run **firebase deploy** does this not overwrite the one created by default?

Comment: There is no hidden default file. If you called `firebase deploy` before, I'm pretty certain you must have had a `firebase.json` to control it. If you can't find it, this is pretty much the minimum I can think of: `{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public" } }
` or use the first sample from this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config